# Voiceglue Expecting '=' after cookie attribute's name

Tags: asterisk, ivr, vxml, error-log, voicexml

I am getting following Voiceglue error while executing in /var/log/dynlog/dynlog

15:35:54:525 EROR OPEN_VXI luke---- callid=[58] |1098905920|58|SEVERE|swi:SBinet|257|SBinet: Expecting '=' after cookie attribute's name|attributeSpec=HttpOnly|attribute=HttpOnly\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the answer, but I have located the code that produces the issue. Maybe we can work together to find out why this happens. I am a Developer but don't yet have an understanding of how this SB* and friends browser works.

```
if (hasValue)
{
  // Now we have to deal with attributes of the form x=y
  if ((p = SBinetHttpUtils::expectChar(p,"=")) == NULL || !*p)
  {
    if (logger)
      logger->Error(257, L"%s%S%s%S", L"attributeSpec", attributeSpec,L"attribute", attribute);
    return NULL;
  }
  p++;
```

Located in *openvxi-3.4+vglue/src/inet/SBinetCookie.cpp*

If you want to stop the infinite looping caused by unhandled errors. The proper way is to add the  tag to the unhandled event thrown by java errors that get thrown infinitely.  This is in the defaults but not in the example from ampersand.com

```
<error>
  <log expr="'*** unhandled event ' + _event + ' thrown : ' + _message + ' ***'"/>
  <prompt bargein="false">
    A technical problem just occurred,
    Please check the logs for more information.
  </prompt>
  <exit/>
</error>
```

Comment: Hi @user1039677 wow tats gr8. I am a newbie in this domain would like have more information on this domain. Me will be happy to work together :)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064867/voiceglue-logger-says-maximum-loop-count-exceeded-there-is-probably-an-infinite) Please this question as well, see if reply.. I have used max errors = 3 in VXML.But I can't understand what errors are occurring and why is it going into infinite loop