# Voiceglue Logger says Maximum loop count exceeded. There is probably an infinite loop of in your VXML document

Tags: asterisk, ivr, vxml, error-log, voicexml

Can Any please explain why this is  happening. what are the possibilities of errors that are been counted as I have set maxerrorcount = 3

```
EROR OPEN_VXI luke---- callid=[68] |1098905920|68|CRITICAL|com.vocalocity.vxi|216|VXIinterpreterRun: Maximum loop count exceeded. There is probably an infinite loop of in your VXML document.|URL
```

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, "infinite loop" means to call same form again and again,
And it was not inserted caller input process(menu, field and record form) in this loop.

For example

```
<form id="errorForm"><!-- Loop Start -->
    <block>
        <!-- something -->
    </block>
    <block>
        <goto next="errorForm" /><!-- Loop End -->
    </block>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bladean's answer is probably the correct one.  There is an alternate possibility.  If an application is structured has looping logic that cycles through the same form or page as it processes data (e.g. a long list), you can trigger these types of checks.  I have had to increase a similar loop counter, for some applications, on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

Voice browser all have infinte loop detection to save them from pitfalls .

It could be something as simple as the "goto where I am coming from example" within the same VXML document example provided here by Bladean Mericle .

It could be burried deeper in a global catch that routes calls to a catch all sub application which in turn bring the flow back to the originating dialog .

Definetely Infinite Loops will never work in VXML .